# Why does my valueOf() method not return the value?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having a little problem with the valueOf() method of an object.
I've got an Array with objects and object literals in it.
Say it's `var Books = [ {"name": "SomeBook"}, {"name": "SomeOtherBook"} ]`.
Now I want to write all the literals into some text-inputs via

```
var i = 0;
book = Books[0];
for (var property in book) {
    if (book.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        editInputs[i].value = property.valueOf();
        //console.log(property.valueOf());
    }
    i++;
}
```

Why is my output the object's name? When I de-comment the log(), I also get "name" instead of SomeBook. Yet, if I use

```
editInputs[0].value = book.name;
```

It inserts `SomeBook`.

Why? I don't want to write every field in a single line...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you literally asking for `book[property]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`property` is a string containing the name of the property.

`valueOf` gives you the primitive value of that, which is still a string containing the name of the property.

If you want to use that string to get the value of the property name which matches the string stored in `property` you need to use:

```
book[property]
```

Comment: Huh, thanks, you're absolutely right.
So the for loop doesn't pass the whole property? But why? Could I make it do that?

Comment: @Silver_Bear — Because that's the point of `in`. Use [`of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) if you want the value.

Answer (score 1):

The variable in a `for` loop is just a string. `valueOf()` just returns the primitive value of the object, but for a string, you just get the string back.

You have to do `book[property]` instead. There isn't really a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
editInputs[i].value = property.valueOf();
```

you should use

```
editInputs[i].value = book[property];
```

Answer (score 1):

If `property` is a property of your `book` object, you will just need to call:

```
book[property]
```

To get its value, because **[.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)** returns the primitive value of the specified object as you can see it in the documentation.